# Entire schema not availabe with API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rake, migrate, dbmigrate

I have a class where I'm not getting the entire schema from the GET API call.

My schema.rb:

```
create_table "jumpsquares", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "name"
 t.integer  "apptype"
 t.string   "url"
 t.string   "ipordns"
 t.text     "description"
 t.datetime "created_at"
 t.datetime "updated_at"
 t.string   "tag"
 t.string   "jscreator"
 t.string   "remotetype"
end
```

The attributes of name, apptype, url, ipordns, description, created_at, and updated_at are available when I perform a GET API call, however the attributes of tag, jscreator, and remotetype are not being retrieved. These particular attributes are the result of 3 different DB migrations to add additional columns.

My remotetype migration:

```
class AddRemoteAccessColumnToJumpSquares < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  add_column :jumpsquares, :remotetype, :string
 end
end
```

My routes.rb:

```
resources :jumpsquares
```

Model:

```
class Jumpsquare < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :apptypes
 has_and_belongs_to_many  :tags

 def self.search(search)
  if search
   where('name ILIKE ? OR ipordns ILIKE ? OR url ILIKE ?', "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%")
  else
  all
  end
 end       
end
```

GET Request

```
resource = RestClient::Resource.new( 'http://localhost:3000/jumpsquares' )
response = resource.get({'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
parsed_response = JSON.parse(response.body)
puts parsed_response

parsed_response.each do |jumpsquare|
 jsresource = RestClient::Resource.new( jumpsquare["url"] )
 jsresponse = jsresource.get({'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
 jsparsed_response = JSON.parse(jsresponse.body)
 puts jsparsed_response
end
```

Comment: What is generating the (I assume) json you are looking at?

Comment: this is just basic rails scaffolding. not using a gem at this point.

Comment: Can you post your model code, as well as the code that handles the `GET` request?

Comment: modified original post to add the model code and GET request